# Creating a two dimensional python array from two one-dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

If I have
`x = [1,2,3,4,5]`
`y = [6,7,8,9,10]`

how can I get a two dimensional array in the form of
    `combined = [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]`

Comment: this is called `zip`

Comment: Calling `zip` gives you an iterator over tuples, like `(1, 6)` instead of `[1, 6]`. If you're just looping over everything, that's just as good as a list of lists, but smaller and faster. If you actually need a list of lists, you need to call `list` on each one—e.g., `[list(pair) for pair in zip(x, y)]`.

Answer (score 0):

A few options.  Numpy should be your go-to tool for performant array operations.  Sticking with your original input values:

`np.array([x,y]).T.tolist()`

With vanilla python, a list comprehension will do:

`[[j,k] for j,k in zip(x,y)]`

Or if you don't mind tuples in place of inner lists, you can use the more terse:

`list(zip(x,y))`

Answer (score -2):

Try numpy if you want:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [6,7,8,9,10]

print(np.reshape(np.dstack((x,y)),[-1,2]))
```

output:

```
[[ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 4  9]
 [ 5 10]]
```

Comment: That code does not produce the output you have provided.